# CGAffineTransfrom: Translating after a rotation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, translation, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to animate a rectangle after I have rotated it with CGAffineTransform. The issue I am having is that the rectangle ends up where it is suppose to be, but the "starting" position for the second transform is not what I expect. This is only an issue because I am animating it. Here is my code below:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) {
        let shift = 200 * CGFloat(2.0.squareRoot() / 2)
        view.transform = view.transform.translatedBy(x: shift, y: 0)
    }
```

`view` is already defined elsewhere and I have already rotated the view with this:

```
let rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (45/180)*CGFloat(M_PI))
view.transform = rotation
```

Before the animation, this is what it looks like: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Kqy.png)

[image]

For some reason, the transformation starts above (a little offscreen) and then moves down into position. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoqdk.png)

[image]

I would like this to happen instead, where it starts from the original picture, and then shifts in the direction of how its rotated. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX5cZ.png)

[image]

Note I did try to apply the same `shift` value to both x and y for the translation but that did not fix my issue.

Comment: Have you tried just animating the x orgin of the desired view? If the lines were horizontal, you would just be sliding the view right a small amount. For example `view.frame.origin.x = 10.0`